# where in sql with multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select 
    hacker_id, name 
from 
    hacker_t 
where 
    hacker_id in (select hacker_t.hacker_id, count(hacker_t.score));
```

This `(select hacker_t.hacker_id, count(hacker_t.score) ...)` returns this result set:

```
hacker_id    cha
-----------------
7             2
```

So, all I want is to

```
select hacker_id, name 
from hacker_t 
where hacker_id in ....
```

the above result set's `hacker_id` column, and not `cha` column.

The problem is I don't know how to do that with the case of `(select...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very lite in details, but here is an example I think you required:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(hacker_id INT, name NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @data VALUES (1, 'Farscape'), (2, 'Firefly')

SELECT hacker_id, name
FROM @data d
WHERE d.hacker_id IN (SELECT hacker_id FROM @data innerd WHERE innerd.name LIKE 'fa%')
```

If you have multiple table joins in the none subquery, you can reference them from the subqueries. E.g. innerd.name = d.name

Comment: The problem I can't have one column returned, I have two, because of count and grouping later in postgres. See the updates

Comment: Arh, you want a join, but your join will be on hacker_id = (SELECT TOP 1  hacker_id... give me a minute I'l squeeze out an alternative. Not understanding which part requires two columns though. I hope your not about the subquery because that doesn't make sense. My queries won't match though, as I have zero experience with postgres.

Comment: Yes, join is a solution, but I want the solution to be with `where` . A solution that will make where in selects the desired column from a multiple column table returned, and this table is not named.

Comment: This is worst case, but you could cast as strings and then join them together... some dirty logic I do in excel at times :D

Comment: That s exactly what I thought, but I thought that's just my dirty mind, seem everyone's!

Comment: Really like no solution with where?

Comment: The question uses a where condition, it just uses an "in" rather an equals

Comment: Sorry again, but your question is so generic and doesn't have enough real world data to postulate a better answer. If you could supply us with a few records and expected outcome I may be able to help more.

Comment: It s alright, I have solved it with join and moved on. By the way, do you know some good sites to practice sql where they provide schemas and data. Hackerank isn't really good on providing schemas and data, one struggles

Comment: For learning advanced code, once I've learned the basic I normally go to codewars... can't say if its any good for sql, but it has been good for all other languages I've used and does support sql. Gives you puzzles and once answered shows you how others did it.

Comment: Thank you so much, can we extend discussion in a chat room and if I need to ask sometimes, I am really sometimes in need of help and extended explanation